# Prevent form from submission if error exists ajax .submit() with .change()

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, submit

So I have this problem with jQuery/ajax code. I have used `.change` method whenever the field is changed. It shows the output whether that email is already taken or not or input field is empty. I know there is `.submit` method and `preventDefault()`, but I'm new to this and I get confused of how to use `.change` with `.submit` at a same time.

```
          pic1 = new Image(20, 20);
          pic1.src="images/abc.jpg";
          $(document).ready(function(){

          function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
             // some regular expressions for email  format validation

      };
            $("#email").change(function() {
            var email = $("#email").val();
            if(isValidEmail(email)){

                $("#status").html('<img 
        style="width:17px;"src="images/abc.jpg" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

                $.ajax({ 

                type: "POST", 
                url: "check.php", 
                data: "email="+ email,
                dataType: 'text',

                    success: function(msg){

                        if(msg == 'OK'){
                         //alert ("success");
                $("#email").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                $("#email").addClass("object_ok");
                $("#status").html('&nbsp;<img src="tick2.gif" 
               align="left"><p><strong style="color:green">This email is available</strong></p>');

            } else {
                //alert ("error");
               $("#email").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
               $("#email").addClass("object_error");
               $("#status").html(msg);
           }
        }

    });

    } else {
      $("#status").html('<font color="red">' + 'Enter Valid 
     Email</font>');
     $("#email").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
     $("#email").addClass("object_error");
   }
  });
 });
```

Comment: You appear to have some code that checks if an email is available.  This is the change ajax call.  Assuming you have a button to submit the email, there's no reason for them to clash or, as you put it, "use `.change` with `.submit` at the same time".  You don't use them at the same time, you use change to check and then later use submit to submit (or button click if you want an ajax submit).

Answer (score 1):

They are both events but
for change and submit they behave differently.
They dont trigger at the same time.

For submit, it is an event to an element when the user is attempting to **submit** a form.
For change, it is an event trigger when the element values **change**.

Source : 

1. https://api.jquery.com/submit/ 

2. https://api.jquery.com/change/

if you want to stop the default behaviour, you can check the added class (object_error) class during the change event.

```
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
    if($('.object_error').length > 0){
         e.preventDefault();  
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean inside the change event block like this             
                `$("#email").change(function() {
                $("registerCompany").on('submit', function (e) {
                  if($('.object_error').length > 0){
                e.preventDefault();  
                return false;
                 }`

Comment: @ZeeshanAli you can put under the change event after the semi colon.
 $("#email").change(function() { //statement});
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {//statement});
They both are different event. One is trigger when u type anything on the email field, the submit event is trigger when you press submit button

Comment: its preventing form to submit if error exist but when we correct these errors its not unbinding submit button i have used code like `$("registerCompany").on('submit', function (e) {
    if($('.object_error').length > 0){
         e.preventDefault();  
         return false;
    }
    else{
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();

    }
  });` but its not working

Comment: Why want to unbind the submit event? should be removing the object_error class , so if there is no object_error class found in the form. it will proceed to submit

Comment: once i enter the incorrect data the code is preventing me from submitting the form but after i update with correct data its still not letting me submit form..i have used unbind just to try but it also not worked

Comment: after you correct the data , go to google console , try to type $('.object_error').length , see is that got any value or not

Comment: it increases the count when incorrect data is entered but after correct input it goes to 0

Comment: try to put 'return true' after the if statement

Comment: i put return true but its also not working `$("registerCompany").on('submit', function (e) {
    if($('.object_error').length > 0){
         e.preventDefault();  
         return false;
    }
    return true;
  });`    here is the code

Comment: can somebody answer my problem im still having this